# How access to object with value of a variable

Tags: javascript, object

Supposte to have an object:

```
var obj = { 'home':1, 'dog':1, 'house':3 }
```

and suppose to have a variable

```
var variable='home';
```

(I don't know if it is possibile)

Now I need access to object in this way obj.variable so variable=home and it seems to do obj.home. I can do something like this? Anyone can help me?

Comment: Use bracket notation to access the key of the object which is dynamic.. `obj[variable]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this `obj[variable]` to access value in json object.

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy:

```
var obj = {'home':1,'dog':1,'house'};
var variable = 'home';

obj[variable] // prints 1
```

It's called [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors).

Answer (score 0):

You can access object properties with 2 ways:

1. With `.` notation.
2. With `[]` notation.

If your object property names are of reserved words or contain empty space, then you can't use . to access them. The only way to access them is `[]`.

So you can access your object property as follows:

`obj[variable] = 10`  // or whatever value you wants to assign to this variable

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the Object:

```
// Setting up Object
var obj = {
    home: 1,
    dog: 1,
    house: "big"
}

// Accesing object 
var home = obj.home;
```

or if you are dynamically generating go with:

// Setting up Object

```
var obj = {
    'home': '1',
    'dog': '1',
    'house': 'big'

}

// Accesing object 
var home = obj["home"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using bracket notation like this `obj[variable]` which has the benefit that the string does not have to be a valid identifier; it can have any value, e.g. "1foo", "!bar!", or even " " (a space).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `obj[variable]` like so:

```
var obj={'home':1,'dog':1,'house':5};
var variable='home';
obj[variable];
```